Objects in blender do not fit into collections/problem with collections in blender
I don't know how to make sure that all my objects in the scene are sorted into collections, because when I add an object to a collection, it remains separately, in the outliner itself. when I try to hide this collection nothing happens, I think it's because of a problem with the collection. I'm a newbie and I'm hoping someone knows why this is happening and can help me resolve this issue.


That depends on what and how you have done it which I cannot in screenshots. You can move objects into a collection with M (which removes it from another) or link (Shift+M) them to a collection (which means they are in both), which can be used for organizing in different categories, like blue and red objects and spheres and cubes as simple examples, where objects can be part of different collections. Apart from that, let's say an object is parented to another, when you move the parent to a collection, the child does not move with it if it's not selected.

As Gordon says, the object can be linked, what does it give if you right click >Unlink?

Gordon, thank you very much, I didn’t even know that you can add collections in different ways (I use shift+m ​​all the time)
